# How to call a function whose name is defined in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing function A's or B's name in a parameter based on the situation to another function C. How can I call it in function C?

Comment: Yes, many duplicates, but no definitive answer so far (which is "bad idea, don't do that").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `A` is defined globally, then `window["A"]()`. However, there's no need to do that in javascript. Just pass the function itself rather than its name:

```
function foo() {...}

// BAD
function callFunc(someName) { window[someName]() }
callFunc("foo")

// GOOD
function callFunc(someFunc) { someFunc() }
callFunc(foo)
```

Comment: or your object[functionname]()

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
window[varName]()
```

assuming it is in global scope

If you have

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
```

then you can do

```
function C(parm) {
  parm();
}
```

if you call it with `C(A)` or `C(B)`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/G4Wwj/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the functions to properties of an object.  Then in your executing function reference the property by name given the parameter passed to the function.

```
var myFuncs = {
   a: function(){
     alert("Hello");
   },
   b: function(){
     alert("Goodbye");
   }
};

function execute(name){
   myFuncs[name]();
}

execute("a");
execute("b");
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/ud6BS/